# Inequality concerning the imaginary parts of a recurrent sequence, Laplacian eigenvectors

Tags: inequalities, eigenvalues, recurrences, laplacian

Let $u=(u_1,\dots,x_n)\in\mathbb{C}^n$ be a sequence that satisfies the cyclic recurrence
$$
\lambda+1 =a_{i-1}\frac {u_{i-1}}{u_i} + (1-a_{i+1})\frac{ u_{i+1} }{u_i } 
$$
with $a_i \in (0,1)$ and $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$, where we use periodic indexing convention $u_{n+1}=u_1,u_0=u_n$. It may be helpful to observe that $u$ is the right eigenvector (with eigenvalue $\lambda$) of a periodic tridiagonal Laplacian-like matrix,
$$
L=\left[\begin{array}{ccccc}
-1 & 1-a_{2} & 0 & 0 & a_n\\
a_{1} & -1 & 1-a_{3} & 0& 0\\
0 & a_{2} & -1 & \dots & 0\\
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots\\
1-a_{1} & 0 & \dots & a_{n-1} & -1
\end{array}\right]
$$

From numerical exploration (by generating many matrices of the form above and finding their eigenvectors), I have found that the following inequality holds:
$$
(\mathrm{Re}\,\lambda+1)^2 + \prod_i \Bigg\vert a_{i-1}\mathrm{Im}\frac{u_{i-1}}{u_i} + (1-a_{i+1})\mathrm{Im}\frac{u_{i+1}^*}{u_i^*}\Bigg\vert^{2/n} \le 1 \,.
$$

How can it be proved?